# With github copilot installed in intellij, how do I type a tab?

Tags: intellij-idea

if the copilot plugin suggests a completion, tab gives me the completion.

How do I ignore the completion and just get a tab (e.g. to indent a line in Python)?

Comment: "Esc" to close completion popup and "Tab" to add indent.

Answer (score 6):

"Esc" to close completion popup and "Tab" to add indent (from https://stackoverflow.com/users/8203759/konstantin-annikov)

Answer (score 0):

If you use **IdeaVim**, `ESC` is not a solution.

1. Disable Copilot: `Shift + Option + Cmd + O`.
2. And freely use `TAB`.
3. Enable Copilot: `Shift + Option + Cmd + O`.